# What does "in a quiet pool" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, popular-refrains

While I was watching a [a True Crime documentary](https://youtu.be/E58u7LZ_-4s?si=iYbVc7VcXKIIz83e&t=55), the narrator said:

> The young pastor, his wife, and their three daughters looked happy and
> had everything they needed to live a comfortable life healthy and
> successful but "in a quiet pool" as they say, in this case, many
> questions remained unanswered.

So what does "in a quiet pool" mean exactly?

Comment: It means "in an area where little or nothing that is unusual or remarkable happens"

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Comment: Is it comparable to "still waters run deep"?

Comment: Not the best writing. A quiet pool [of water], like a pond in the forest, for example.

Comment: @TimR I don't think so. In that proverb, "still waters" is usually a metaphor for a placid person, not a place.

Comment: @Barmar I  haven't heard the expression and don't understand the relationship of the quiet pool to "many questions remain unanswered".

Comment: @TimR Now I see what you're talking about. I was having trouble parsing the run-on sentence -- I  initially thought "in a quiet pool" was where they were living their comfortable life. So I think you might be right that it's a place equivalent of that proverb.